# How to set prefix to all keys of url rules?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

I want to set prefix for all keys of urlManager rules. At the moment I write rules like that:

```
'rules' => [
    'api' => '_public/site/index',
    'api/<controller>/<action>' => '_public/<controller>/<action>',      
     etc
]
```

I want to avoid copy/past-ing of `api` prefix to all rules. Because it could be 500 rules.

Is there a way to define somewhere a prefix in order to *Yii* placed it for every rule key itself?

`$prefix` and `$prefixRoute` is setting up prefix for values, but I want for keys.

Maybe this can be done by using `.htaccess`? But I don't know what should I write there.

Comment: This may be help full for you to understand the way how the `api` must be implemented: https://klisl.com/yii2-api-rest.html and here from official yii2 github : https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/rest-versioning.md

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco yes, I know it, thanks. But I want something different)) doesn't matter what and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a line to config file:

```
$config = [

    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // some code
            'baseUrl' => '/api',   // <--- this line
        ], 
    ]
]
```

and it worked.

`$baseUrl` - The relative URL for the application. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$baseUrl-detail

Answer (score 0):

The [`yii\web\GroupUrlRule`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-groupurlrule) and its `$prefix` property is exactly what you are looking for.

In your case:

```php
rules => [
    // ...
    new \yii\web\GroupUrlRule([
        'prefix' => 'api',
        'rules' => [
            '<controller>/<action>' => '_public/<controller>/<action>',
            // ... other /api/_ routes
        ],
    ]),
    // ... other rules
]
```

I'm not sure if adding rule like this `'/' => '_public/site/index',` into the group would work for `/api` route or if you would have to set that one explicitly outside of group rule. If you are going to set rule for `/api` outside of group rule it might be better to put it before the group rule.

Comment: Yes, I tried GroupUrlRule. But as the result it adds the prefix to a "value" of each rule, not to keys. i.e. `'' => 'site/index'` gives me as a result  `'' => 'api/site/index'`,  and `'<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>'` gives me `'<controller>/<action>' => 'api/<controller>/<action>'`. I want opposite. I need `'<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>'` convert into `'api/<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>'` ...... maybe I did something wrong. Well, I'll try it again then

Answer (score 0):

The GroupUrlRule with properties: prefix, routePrefix and rules will be enough. You can use it as follows:

```
new GroupUrlRule([
    'prefix' => 'api',
    'routePrefix' => '',
    'rules' => [
          '' => '_public/site/index',
          '<controller>/<action>' => '_public/<controller>/<action>',
    ]
])
```

Add this to the rules under urlManager in the main config file.